# Jenkins CLI setup for Jenkins users - Approach

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I have Jenkins 1.647 running in redhat server. I am try to create the jobs from command line using Jenkins Jobs in Execute Shell based on parameters. 
I tried like below but none of the commands are working. My jenkins authentication is based on ldap.

Executing these commands via Jenkins Execute Shell.
command-1

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://buildserver:8080/jenkins/ get-job job-template -i /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
[WARN] Failed to authenticate with your SSH keys. Proceeding as anonymous
No such job 'job-template'
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar get-job JOB [--username VAL] [--password VAL] [--password-file VAL]
Dumps the job definition XML to stdout.
 JOB                 : Name of the job
 --username VAL      : User name to authenticate yourself to Jenkins
 --password VAL      : Password for authentication. Note that passing a
                       password in arguments is insecure.
 --password-file VAL : File that contains the password
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

command-2

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://buildserver:8080/jenkins/ --username my-name --password-file /tmp/password-file

/tmp/password-file
xxxxx
```

Is there a way to make the above commands work using Jenkins users API token. Please suggest.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://buildserver:8080/jenkins/ -auth USER:TOKEN get-job job-template
```

You need to create an API token under `JENKINS_URL:PORT/user/YOUR_USER/configure`